# Raspberry Pi Accelerometer and i2c

Tags: python, pi-2, i2c

I have recently bought an mma7361l accelerometer. I simply want to be able to read data from. It seems as if I need to use I2c, but that's all I know, there is a lack of documentation for this accelerometer. May I get some help with wiring this accelerometer, using I2c, and reading info that I can use in python?  Thank you.

Comment: The mma7361l is not an I2C device.  Presumably you have bought a module incorporating the mma7361l and including an I2C interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MMA7361 (assuming you've got the bare module) produces 3 analog outputs. Unfortunately, the Raspberry Pi has no analog inputs. However, you could use an analog-to-digital converter chip (e.g. the MCP3008) to read those analog outputs. See here for a tutorial on using the MCP3008 with the GPIO Zero Python library: http://raspi.tv/2016/using-mcp3008-to-measure-temperature-with-gpio-zero-and-raspio-pro-hat

The alternative is to use an Arduino (see this tutorial: http://www.electroschematics.com/10467/learn-use-mma7361/) and transmit to the Pi over serial.

Comment: Thank you, I will buy the chip, I am not very proficient in reading input on the raspberry pi through python. Could you help me, or give me a program to use once I receive the chip. Thank you.

Comment: It's pretty easy, especially if you use GPIO Zero. As I said in the answer, if you go to: http://raspi.tv/2016/using-mcp3008-to-measure-temperature-with-gpio-zero-and-raspio-pro-hat there's a pretty good example on there.  If you run into problems, can you contact me via my blog: http://www.recantha.co.uk/blog as I don't get notification when someone replies on here. :-)